# Retrieval of 3D coordinates from disparity map

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to retrieve 3D coordinates from disparity map. I have obtained a set of points, but I am not sure whether they could be trusted. I have used the usual commands from OpenCV which could be seen below. The intrinsic parameters of the stereo cameras have been processed by a separate tool, which rectifies the input images as well.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
imgL = cv2.imread('C:/Internship/left010.flt.pgm',0)
imgR = cv2.imread('C:/Internship/right010.flt.pgm',0)
 #Calculate disparity
stereo = cv2.StereoSGBM(minDisparity = 0, numDisparities = 160, SADWindowSize =    11, disp12MaxDiff = 1, uniquenessRatio = 20, speckleWindowSize = 100, speckleRange = 2) 
disparity = stereo.compute(imgL,imgR)/16
 #Calculate Q matrix
cx = 630.0493
cy = 472.6702
fx = 1887.663
fy = 1880.201
cameraMatrix1 = np.mat([[fx, 0, 0],[0, fy, 0],[cx, cy, 1]])
cameraMatrix2 = np.mat([[fx, 0, 0],[0, fy, 0],[cx, cy, 1]])
distCoeffs1 = np.array([0,0,0,0,0])
distCoeffs2 = np.array([0,0,0,0,0])
R = np.mat([[0.9743, 0.0335, -0.2227],[-0.0379, 0.9991, -0.0155], [0.2220, 0.0236, 0.9747]])#Rotation Matrix
T = np.array([ 0.2042, -0.0019, 0.0313]) #Translation Vector
R1 = np.mat(np.empty((3,3)))
R2 = np.float32(np.empty((3,3)))
P1 = np.float32(np.empty((3,4)))
P2 = np.float32(np.empty((3,4)))
Q = np.float32(np.empty((4,4)))
cv2.stereoRectify(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, (w,h), R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, -1, (0,0))
 #Calculate3Dpoints
points = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(disparity, Q)
```

The images can be viewed here [image: left image] [image: right image] [image: disparity map]

The reason I am being skeptical is that I am having negative values in the "points" matrix. For example the Z values range from [-388.438, -194.219,..., -2.443, 388.438, inf]. I am not sure if this is because of the defect pixels in the disparity map.
I tried to slice a portion of the original image by creating a mask using the x and y coordinates and it does give me some output, please have a look below:

```
z = points[:,:,2]
val, count = np.unique(z, return_counts = True)
rec = np.logical_and(z>-300,  z< -5)
mask = np.invert(rec)
imgL[mask] = 0
plt.imshow(imgL,'gray')
plt.show()
```

The output image is [image: sliced image] I suppose that if any image is indexed at some random point, then there will be some output image. So basically, I want to check the validity of the 3D points and I don't know how. Please help me verify them. Please let me now if any further information is required.